# Unable to get Image real path from image uri in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to the get the real path of my image from its uri but getting null in return as path. I am using the following referenced code to get the real path.

`https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626`

Sample Image Uri: **content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A102173**

Returned Real Path: **null**

Comment: What are you trying to do with the real path of the image? For security reasons you are prevented from getting an absolute path to files in newer android APIs

Comment: Very well. You should not try to get 'a real path'. You have a nice content scheme uri. You can use it for all file actions.

Comment: @Rafsanjani, Has nothing to do with security. If you do it right you will get a nice file system path. The path will be correct but not usable as the app will not have a read permission for it. Hence trying to get 'a real path' is useless. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it didn't work for me but you can try [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414749/18387410) as it has apparently worked for many people's. If you still get null you can do what I have done.

I tried many ways but I was still getting the result null. basically, I am trying to upload an image from local storage compress it, and used the compressed image.

```
val path = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`try {
                        val file = File(path, "/Image")
                        file.mkdirs()
                        val image = File(file.absolutePath, "image1.jpeg")
                        intent1.data = image.absolutePath.toUri()
                        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri))
                        val array = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                        val out =  FileOutputStream(image)
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70,out)
                        out.flush()
                        out.close()
                        Log.d("Path", image.absolutePath)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).