# Android Uri to Filesize

Tags: java, android, uri, filesize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Get the size of a file in resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049926/android-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-resources)

I want to upload a file to a WebServer. To show the progress of the upload I need to know the complete size of the file. Since I have only the Uri of the file (got it from an Intent), I have no chance to get at the file's size. My workaround is to open an InputStream and count the bytes that are read on this InputStream. But this is circuitous. Is there an easier/conventional way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I opted to close this one as a duplicate instead of the other one, since the linked duplicate has an accepted answer and this here hasn't, even though time-wise this question was asked first.

Comment: It would have been useful to include a link to the duplicate so future viewers are not forced to now search for a variation of this question when they end up here first.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The linked question is specifically related to resources (as in R.drawables, etc), not just files from an Intent. It's pretty different.

Comment: I agree, it seems different, dunno why I closed it as a duplicate now. You should flag it for reopening, I'm no longer a moderator so I don't have special powers in these tags.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), under the header *Examine document metadata*, for an example method showing how to get display name and size of a document from a given `Uri`.

Answer (score 27):

You can get the size of the file in bytes thus:

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
long size = f.length();
```

Comment: File expects java.net.URI, but I have andorid.net.Uri

Comment: This SO post shows how to convert between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559902/android-how-can-i-convert-android-net-uri-object-to-java-net-uri-object/560006#560006

Comment: This always returns 0 for me, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53363407/812919)

Comment: Working well good solution