# Get the size of an Android file resource?

Tags: android, file, resources, size

I have a video file in the raw folder in my resources. I want to find the size of the file. 
I have this piece of code:

```
Uri filePath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.FileTransfer/" + R.raw.video);
                File videoFile = new File(filePath.getPath());
                Log.v("LOG", "FILE SIZE "+videoFile.length());
```

But it always gives me that the size is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `File` for resources. Use `Resources` or `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` to the resource, then call the `available()` method on it.

Like this:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nameOfFile);
int sizeOfInputStram = is.available(); // Get the size of the stream
```

Comment: Never had a problem with this one?! This method is supposed to return `an estimated number of bytes that can be read`, not necessarily the real file size, and the documentation clearly discourages its use...
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

Comment: Well, the documentation refers to generic streams that may take a while to retrieve data, like network streams. In a resource, the exact size is always known and available.

Answer (score 24):

Try this lines:

```
InputStream ins = context.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.video)
int videoSize = ins.available();
```

Comment: Same question / comment than I just posted under @EboMike's answer. Never had any problem this way??

Comment: What `openRawResource()` returns is not a normal `InputStream` but an `AssetInputStream`. This subclass overrides `available()` and _is_ able to provide reliable information.

Comment: @MarcoW. Umm, not according to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.AssetInputStream.html#available()

Comment: @goldilocks: Well, yes! If you take a look at the documentation for `InputStream.available()`, you'll see that this is where the explanation comes from. `AssetInputStream` uses exactly the same text in its JavaDoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available() But the source shows that `AssetInputStream.available()` overrides the superclass's method and gets its result from a native method: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#AssetManager.AssetInputStream.available%28%29

Comment: @MarcoW. I don't doubt that or the fact that it there are implementations (*currently* including android) where it works.  But if your standard is *what the API actually commits to*, then the API doesn't commit to this.  If it doesn't work tomorrow on some device, it will be your fault for trusting in something basic programming principles say you should not! Also, there is a safe, by the book method -- see shem's answer.  That's the canonical one, IMO.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor sampleFD = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.video);
long size = sampleFD.getLength()
```

Comment: That looks much safer than other answers.

Comment: +1 But it won't work by default on a lot of file types because `aapt` compresses them -- for a solution to that see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743169/how-can-i-use-openrawresourcesfd/19743170

Answer (score 10):

Slight variation to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906928/812919) by [@shem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239718)

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(fileUri,"r");
long fileSize = afd.getLength();
afd.close();
```

Where `fileUri` is of type Android [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri)

Answer (score 2):

### Reuseable Kotlin Extensions

You can call these on a context or activity. They are exception safe

```
fun Context.assetSize(resourceId: Int): Long =
    try {
        resources.openRawResourceFd(resourceId).length
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        0
    }
```

This one is not as good as the first, but may be required in certain cases

```
fun Context.assetSize(resourceUri: Uri): Long {
    try {
        val descriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(resourceUri, "r")
        val size = descriptor?.length ?: return 0
        descriptor.close()
        return size
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        return 0
    }
}
```

If you'd like a simple way to get a different byte representation, you can use these

```
val Long.asKb get() = this.toFloat() / 1024
val Long.asMb get() = asKb / 1024
val Long.asGb get() = asMb / 1024
```