# What's up with AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()?

Tags: java, android

I have an uncompressed binary file in res/raw that I was reading this way:

```
public byte[] file2Bytes (int rid) {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(rid);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        int len = (int)afd.getLength();
        buffer = new byte[len];
        in.read(buffer, 0, len);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.w(ACTNAME, "file2Bytes() fail\n"+ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

However, `buffer` did not contain what it was supposed to.  The source file is 1024 essentially random bytes (a binary key).  But `buffer`, when written out and examined, was not the same. Amongst unprintable bytes at beginning appeared *"res/layout/main.xml"* (the literal path) and then further down, part of the text content of another file from res/raw. **O_O?**

Exasperated after a while, I tried:

```
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(rid);
            //FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(afd.getFileDescriptor());
            FileInputStream in = afd.createInputStream();
```

Presto, I got the content correctly -- this is easily reproducible.

So the [relevant API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#getFileDescriptor%28%29) read:

> **public FileDescriptor getFileDescriptor ()**
>
> Returns the FileDescriptor that can be used to read the data in the
>   file.
>
> **public FileInputStream createInputStream ()**
>
> Create and return a new auto-close input stream for this asset. This
>   will either return a full asset
>   AssetFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream, or an underlying
>   ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream depending on whether the the
>   object represents a complete file or sub-section of a file. You should
>   only call this once for a particular asset.

Why would a FileInputStream() constructed from getFileDescriptor() end up with garbage whereas createInputStream() gives proper access?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just calling `openRawResource()` to get a stream directly, rather than fussing around with all the indirection?

Comment: agreed with CommonsWare, but if you still want to play with AFD, see AFD.getStartOffset()

Comment: @CommonsWare See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743169/how-can-i-use-openrawresourcesfd/19743170

Comment: @pskink I guess that's it, as a FileDescriptor "that can be used to read the data in the file" is not necessarily an fd that represents just the file...I guess.  Be nice if there was a explicit caveat in the docs though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per pskink's comment, the FileDescriptor returned by AssetFileDescriptor() is apparently not an fd that refers *just* to the file -- it perhaps refers to whatever bundle/parcel/conglomeration aapt has made of the resources.

```
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(rid);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        in.skip(afd.getStartOffset());
```

Turns out to be the equivalent of the `FileInputStream in = afd.createInputStream()` version.

I suppose there is a hint in the difference between "create" (something new) and "get" (something existing). :/

Answer (score 0):

AssetFileDescriptor can be thought of as the entry point to the entire package's assets data.

I have run into the same issue and solved it finally.

If you want to manually create a stream from an AssetFileDescriptor, you have to skip n bytes to the requested resource. It is like you are paging thru all the available files in one big file.

Thanks to pskink! I had a look at the hex content of the jpg image I want to acquire, it starts with -1. The thing is, there are two jpg images. I did not know, so I arbitrarily skip 76L bytes. Got the first image!