# How to get File length of an image Uri

Tags: android, kotlin

i have an image Uri File and i need to check if that file is larger than 1mb.
here is a piece of what i tried:

```
val uriFile  = selectedPhotoUri!!.toFile()
uriFileLength = (uriFile.length().div(1024))
```

application crashed

also I've tried that:

```
val uriFile :File = File(selectedPhotoUri.toString())
uriFileLength = (uriFile1.length().div(1024))
```

`uriFileLength` always returns as 0 
also i am using Kotlin, I searched on this forum but only found java codes.
thanks in advance.

Comment: 567.div(1024) is 0 ;-). You have to query() the getContentResolver() with the uri you obtained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the size of an Android file resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049926/get-the-size-of-an-android-file-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast either your `.length()` . or `1024` into a *float* or a *double*, otherwise the operation will return an integer which in case the file size is less than 1024 will return 0.

**For example:**

**Integers**

`256 / 1024 = 0`

**Doubles or Float**

`256 / 1024 = 0.25`

So you can have something like:

```
fun File.getFileSizeFloat(): Float {
    return this.length().toFloat().div(1024)
}

fun File.getFileSizeDouble(): Double {
    return this.length().toDouble().div(1024)
}

// call to get file size
uriFile.getFileSizeDouble()

// or
uriFile.getFileSizeFloat()
```

Comment: i tried your method but still it's returning 0.0 now, i didnt downvote btw.

Comment: If it still returning 0, then your URI is not valid. If you try `uriFile.exists()`, does it return `true`?

Comment: tried uriFile.exists() returned false, i think my problem is that my uri file can not be transformed into a file by using File() or .toFile() , also the suggested answer is in java and can't be used in kotlin? correct me if i am wrong , i started learning kotlin not long ago. thank you

Comment: @nickisra the answer is in Kotlin, and they are extension functions which are only available in Kotlin. How do you get your URI? I will suggest to use the `path` to create the File object, from there my answer should be sufficient.  See how to get the path from URI:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7726604/3330058

Comment: thanks for your help, i solved the problem 1 min ago by using documentFile dependency

Comment: @nickisra nice to hear that you solved it. If my answer helped to solve the initial question of the file size,  please mark it as the correct one.