# How to delete a video recorded using an Intent with ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE?

Tags: android, android-intent, video, uri

I would like to remove a video that has been previously recorded using an Intent:

```
Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(
                  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

The method onActivityResult() get the recorded video as Intent data. I try to obtain the recorded file and delete it.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Code for modify and copy the video
    try {
            Uri androidUri = data.getData();
            File file = new File(new java.net.URI(androidUri.toString()));
            file.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI: content://media/external/video/media/177.

Does somebody know how can I get the path of the recorded video and move or delete it?

Comment: Have you tried just passing the `URI` to the `File` constructor? Example...`File file = new File(uri);`

Comment: Yes, but the File constructor needs an URI not an Uri. I should convert the android.net.Uri to an java.net.URI. This question is unresolved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559902/android-how-can-i-convert-android-net-uri-object-to-java-net-uri-object.

Comment: If I try: File file = new File(new java.net.URI(androidUri.toString())); I get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI: content://media/external/video/media/177 . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/android-get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) has how to get the path from a content URI. You should be able to pass its result to the `File` constructor.