# Uri.toString() returns a reference instead of the String

Tags: android, string, reference, uri

When attempting to execute this code in an Android Activity:

```
Uri testurl = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Log.v("HTTPGet", "testurl.toString == " + testurl.toString());
```

the only output in Logcat is a reference to a string, but not the string itself:

```
HTTPGet(23045): testurl.toString == [Landroid.net.Uri;@4056e398
```

How can I print the actual string?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, and it gives me 
08-11 07:36:40.554: VERBOSE/HTTPGet(364): `testurl.toString == http://www.google.com`

Comment: @Nick, might this log line be coming from somewhere else? Are you logging the phrase `testurl.toString` anywhere else? Somehow, an array is being printed out, as indicated by `[L` ...

Comment: @Ray Toal You're right and I apologize, the context was not proper. I should have not assumed. The uri.toString() context is in a private class that extends an AsyncTask and the uri is created outside of that class in its parent (calling) class. Is it because of these class boundaries the issue arises? Or is it because I'm using an external resource (JSoup)? Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/Cei7exin

Comment: Oh of course, this all makes perfect sense now!  I will update my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (Scratch it)**

`Uri.toString` writes out a description of the URI object from the class Uri.

Documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

To get the human readable version, invoke the getter methods defined for the class.

**THE REAL ANSWER**

The OP has clarified and provided the actual code.  Here is the actual context:

```
@Override
protected Document doInBackground(Uri... arg0) {
    Document ret = null;
    Log.v("HTTPGet", "Uri.toString == " + arg0.toString());
    try {
        ret = Jsoup.connect(arg0.toString()).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What is happening here is that the parameter `arg0` has type `Uri[]`, namely an **array of Uri**.  The dot-dot-dot syntax is Java's "varargs".  It means the parameter is actually an array, but rather than passing an array in the call, you can pass any number of arguments that Java will bundle up into an array.

Because you are using a third party library, you have to override this method which takes in one **or more** Uris.  You are assuming that only one will be used.  If this is the case, you should instead write

```
Log.v("HTTPGet", "Uri.toString == " + arg0[0].toString());
```

If you really will be processing multiple uris, use a for-loop to go through and log all of them.

Make sure to fix your `Jsoup.connect` line too.  It doesn't want a messy array string. :)

Comment: Actually, the documentation says that `toString` "returns the encoded string representation of this URI. Example: "http://google.com/". The behaviour OP is experiencing is therefore unexpected, to say the least.

Comment: In that case convert the android Uri to a Java URI and call `toString` on that: information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559902/android-how-can-i-convert-android-net-uri-object-to-java-net-uri-object

Comment: @Xion Agreed that this is odd, `[L` indicates an array.

Comment: Thanks for the newly clarified answer! I'm new to Java from C++ and this helped clarify a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Invoke getEncodedPath() on Uri to get the string in it.

Something like below

```
// imageUri is an Uri extracted from Intent 
String filePath = imageUri.getEncodedPath();
```

This filePath will have string content as defined in Uri. i.e. content:/media.../id

Shash